# Issues when compiling TeX files with Vim and LaTeX-suite

Tags: pdftex, compiling, vim, dvi-mode

I'm having problems compiling a TeX file with [LaTeX-suite](http://vim-latex.sourceforge.net/) on Ubuntu.
In my `.vimrc`, I have the following lines :

```
 filetype plugin on
 set grepprg=grep\ -nH\ $*
 filetype indent on
 let g:tex_flavor='latex'
```

When I go to the menu and tell it to compile, if I put `.dvi`, a `.dvi` file is 
generated but I ask for a `.pdf`, nothing happens.

Can anyone give me some pointers on this?

Comment: Can you run `pdflatex` on your `.tex` file manually? Does changing the target format (`:TTarget pdf`), which should set both compiler and view target, help?

I assume that you have set the compile target to `pdf` instead of `*.pdf` which produces an error message, and that you run "compile" after you have changed the compiler target.

Comment: @Nicolas this question is duplicate of https://superuser.com/questions/186283/compile-tex-files-to-pdf-as-default-in-gvim-with-latexsuite-plugin

Answer (score 3):

+1 to what jofel said. Just use

```
:TTarget pdf
```

then type `\ll` and that should compile your .tex file with pdflatex instead of latex.

Comment: How can I set this in my `.vimrc` so that all time when I press `\ll` it produces `pdf`?

Comment: @alhelal see https://superuser.com/questions/186283/compile-tex-files-to-pdf-as-default-in-gvim-with-latexsuite-plugin